# Accessibility asp.net label HTML5

Tags: asp.net, html, accessibility

I have an asp.net label control which is associated with a server control. However depending on runtime conditions sometimes this server control is invisible. Hence when the server control is invisible the accessibility tool states that there is no server control for this label. A kinda dirty fix is to self reference the label as follows:

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelId" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="LabelId" />
```

This passes the accessibility tool in all circumstances but it doesn't seem like a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

It tells label, where the focus should go once the label is clicked.

As shown in the below example. If you click on "Enter First Name" label, focus will go to FirstName textbox and if you click on "Enter Last Name" label, focus will go to LastName textbox.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text="Enter First Name" AssociatedControlID="txtFirstName" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" />

        <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text="Enter Last Name" AssociatedControlID="txtLastName" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
```

[Label.AssociatedControlID Property (System.Web.UI.WebControls) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.associatedcontrolid?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_Label_AssociatedControlID)